# In Mule 4 how do I get error handling to use the payload?

Tags: mule, mule-component, mulesoft, mule4

I am using Mule 4 to make a flow and on the error handling I want it to transform the message to something that uses the existing payload.

My code is

```
transactionNotification: {
    "Testout": "Band", 
    "errorNotification": p("api.name"),
    "transactionCode": p("notification.errorCode"),
    "transactionStatus": p("notification.error"),
    remark: {
        messageCode: p("notification.messageCode"),
        messageText: payload
    }
}
```

and I get the error

> Scripting language error on expression '%dw 2.0 output
>
> ### application/json
>
> transactionNotification: {
>         "Testout": "B...'. Reason: Unable to resolve reference of payload..

The same code seems to work in the normal flow and the error goes away
 when I delete payload.

Comment: Still unclear about what you are asking, where do u input reference of payload value for `Testout`, is it hardcoded value ?

Comment: Are you getting the error in the Studio or while the project is executing?

Answer (score 1):

instead of using #[payload], please use #[message.payload]

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve this using a "Set Variable" to a java object.

Name: payloadString

Value: #[payload]

MIME Type
application/java

I can then use it like you

```
{
  "Testout": "Band", 
  "errorNotification": p("api.name"),
  "transactionCode": p("notification.errorCode"),
  "transactionStatus": p("notification.error"),
  remark: {
    messageCode: p("notification.messageCode"),
    messageText: (vars.payloadString as String)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

payload is a **runtime** property and **dynamic**, even though it shows unable to resolve reference of payload, that could be a **warning**, you can ignore it. As it is a runtime property, the value of payload could be resolved when you build and run the project.